# Internet traffic monitor for ubuntu

Tags: internet

I installed netspeed but it seems that run only on gnome desktop
is there another internet traffic monitor for ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

NTM is a monitor for network and internet traffic.

To download, click [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netramon/?source=dlp)

Also check out [ipac-ng](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMonitorInternetTrafficTotals)

Answer (score 0):

System Monitor (gnome-system-monitor) has a "basic" internet usage meter

It gets reset to 0 on every reboot, and doesn't provide much detail

I would advise using others suggested in the answers

Answer (score 0):

vnstat works well for me...

> sudo apt install vnstat

to run in terminal

> vnstat

vnstat for monthly and estimated

https://www.spinup.com/getting-started-with-vnstat-on-ubuntu-18-04/
make it active on startup

> sudo systemctl enable vnstat.service

it even does an estimate of the monthly usage... next step is to get it into the top bar, there are extensions that can get text up there