# big uploading wifi is availble before booting

Tags: nethogs

It seems that if I have my tether on before booting, there is a strong upload from my system to the phone.  However, it also seems that nothing is being uploaded from my phone to the internet.

How can I know what it is.  I see something like nethogs, but I do not see anything really eating bandwidth.  but I do not know how to give it an  whatever that is...

I think it might be related to sending an error report, but it seems to never stop...many times.. 40 or 50 mb..  if I reboot sometimes.. it stops.. sometimes not.  It does not happen all of the time, but I have narrowed it down to doing this upload thing if I have the tether on before booting.  Then it does this uploading stuff.
Here is a picture of nethogs NOT showing me who it is.
[image]

Please help quickly.  I am in Myanmar and this can kill my $10 per month budget.

Is it at virus or something to do with a browser synching.. or something.
I have chrome, moz, and opera.  but they are not running as far as I can see.  I just rebooted (twice) until it finally stopped.  maybe it was finished uploading and phishing my emails or something.

Comment: This link contains the answer already by installing either htop or wireshark apps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307318/which-application-can-i-use-for-a-network-traffic-monitor

Comment: I think I get this when I have the connection going before I log in.  Not sure yet.